# Show $cartItemsCount for each Magento website ID

Tags: magento, php

I have a magento multistore website where we have a landing page that links to three stores (and each store is on it’s own subdomain).  The carts/checkouts are all separate, but we have the customers set as global so they can navigate to each store without relogging in.  We would like to show a summary block on the landing page that lists the 3 carts and the number of items in each, as simple as

Cart for Site A has 1 item 
Cart for Site B is empty 
Cart for Site C has 2 items

It seems like it should be simple, like:

```
 $_cartQty = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount()
```

but I am having a terrible time finding any answers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();  //get total items in cart
$total = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); //get total price
```

Comment: Ok - this works for each individual site, but if I want to show the $count of items in Cart A on Site B?  This doesn't do that.